# Why does declarative_authorization break the functionality of my controller? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

I have a `Coupons` controller with two actions.

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
  filter_resource_access

  def index
    @coupons = Coupon.all
  end

  #generates 10 new coupons on each call
  def generate
    plan_id = params[:plan_id]
    numdays = params[:num_days]

    (1..10).each do |i|
      validChars = %w{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 a A b B d D e E f g G h H j J k K m M n N p P q Q r R t T }.to_a

      code = (0...6).map{ validChars[ rand(validChars.size) ] }.join

      coupon = Coupon.new
      coupon.code = code
      coupon.plan_id = plan_id
      coupon.active = false
      coupon.subdays = numdays
      coupon.save
    end
    redirect_to :coupons_path
  end

end
```

The generate action is invoked in my view like this:

```
<h2 class="page-title">Coupons</h2>
<div class="main">
   <%= form_tag "coupons/generate" do -%>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'user[plan_id]', "1" %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'user[num_days]', "150" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Generate 10 Coupons!", :class => "primary button" %>
   <% end -%>
    <table border="0" class="list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th><th>Plan</th><th>Duration</th><th>Activated</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% if !@coupons.nil? %>
            <% @coupons.each do |coupon| %>
            <tr class="<%#= list_entry or list_entry_alt %>">
                <td><%= coupon.code %></td>
                <td><%= coupon.plan_id  %></td>
                <td><%= coupon.subdays %> days</td>
                <td><% if coupon.started.nil? == true  %>
                    <%= 'Not yet' %>
                    <% else %>
                    <%= time_ago_or_time_stamp coupon.started %>
                    <% end %>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

My `config/authorization_rules.rb` looks like this:

```
has_permission_on [:coupons], :to => [:index, :show, :step, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy, :generate]
```

The error all of the above throws is this:

```
filter_access_to tried to find Coupon from params[:id] (nil), because attribute_check is enabled and @coupon isn't set, but failed: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Coupon without an ID
Completed 404 Not Found in 245ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Coupon without an ID):
```

However, once I change the `filter_resource_access` to `filter_access_to :all, :except => :generate` it doesn't give me the error anymore and kinda works.

i.e. it produces some of the coupon codes that I am looking for, but it doesn't include the plan_id number or the number of days in the output in the view.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: By the way, it does restrict the right people...i.e. only the specified roles can view the `coupons index view`. So the filter partly works.

Comment: Please don't do `if coupon.started.nil? == true`. Just `if coupon.started.nil?` will do.

Comment: K. Fixed! What about the rest of it? :)

Answer (score 2):

filter_resource_access triggers the declarative auth framework to perform a lookup on the :id parameter for your resource (in non- collection/creator methods).

In your example, it would do a @coupon = Coupon.find(params[:id]) and set up that member variable for your controller. However, since there is no params[:id] coming in to that action through that route, it fails.

The way around it, while still preserving your controller permissions is pretty easy. Just put this at the top of your controller on the filter_resource_access line:

```
filter_resource_access :additional_collection => { :generate => :read } 
# I tried the two lines below but to no avail
#filter_resource_access :additional_collection => { :generate => :read }, :no_attribute_check => [ :generate ]
# filter_access_to :generate, :attribute_check => false
```

This maintains your permission checks against the other controller actions as well as the "generate" action but exempts the "generate" method from an automatic finder lookup.

For more info see:
http://rubydoc.info/github/stffn/declarative_authorization/master/Authorization/AuthorizationInController/ClassMethods

Comment: What does 'read' do here? I got it to work, but slightly differently. I used - filter_resouce_access :collection => [[:generate, :index], :index]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `filter_resource_access` is treating all the actions in the controller as if they're dealing with a single resource and attempting to do `Coupon.find(params[:id])`. By changing it to this:

```
filter_access_to :all, :except => :generate
```

You are telling it to *not* run that method before that action, meaning it won't try to find a coupon.

Comment: So how do I get it to 'function properly' but still be restricted only to the roles I have specified in my `authorization_rules.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with filter_resource_access it assumes the controller uses default resource actions and tries to find a dealer if params[:id] for the actions that are not standard crud.
What you need to do is to add

```
filter_access_to :all
```

And add the corresponding rule for :generate to your authorization_rules.rb.
Like

```
role :someone do
    has_permission_on :coupon, :to => :generate
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Declarative Authorization needs you to declare coupon as an instance variable.

In your controller, try changing `coupon = Coupon.new` to `@coupon = Coupon.new` (Obviously change the subsequent lines accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

filter_resource_access tries to create the resource object for you, so you needs to look at the `:additional_member` or `:additional_collection` options, or use the `except` option as you noted.

As for the missing plan parameters, are you sure they come in as `params[:plan_id]` ?  check your devel logs to see what the incoming params look like.

You also aren't checking the success of the `save` call, so if there is an error, you won't know it.